# search within an array with a condition

Tags: vb.net, arrays, search

I have two array I'm trying to compare at many levels. Both have the same structure with 3 "columns.

The first column contains the polygon's ID, the second a area type, and the third, the percentage of each area type for a polygone.

So, for many rows, it will compare, for example, ID : 1 Type : aaa % : 100
But for some elements, I have many rows for the same ID. For example, I'll have ID 2, Type aaa, 25% --- ID 2, type bbb, 25% --- ID 2, type ccc, 50%. And in the second array, I'll have  ID 2, Type aaa, 25% --- ID 2, type bbb, 10% --- ID 2, type eee, 38% --- ID 2, type fff, 27%.

here's a visual example..
[image: PrintScreen]

So, my function has to compare these two array and send me an email if there are differences.
(I wont show you the real code because there are 811 lines). The first "if" condition is

```
if array1.id = array2.id Then
if array1.type = array2.type Then
if array1.percent = array2.percent Then
zone_verification = True
Else
zone_verification = False
```

The probleme is because there are more than 50 000 rows in each array. So when I run the function, for each "array1.id", the function search through 50 000 rows in array2. 50 000 searchs for 50 000 rows.. it's pretty long to run!

I'm looking for something to get it running faster. How could I get my search more specific. Example : I have many id "2" in the array1. If there are many id "2" in the array2, find it, and push all the array2.id = 3 in a "sub array" or something like that, and search in these specific rows. So I'll have just X rows in array1 to compare with X rows in array 2, not with 50 000. and when each "id 2" in array1 is done, do the same thing for "id 4".. and for "id 5"...

Hope it's clear. it's almost the first time I use VB.net, and I have this big function to get running.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here's what I wanna do.

I have two different layers in a geospatial database. Both layers have the same structure. They are a "spatial join" of the land parcels (55 000), and the land use layer. The first layer is the current one, and the second layer is the next one we'll use after 2015.

So I have, for each "land parcel" the percentage of each land use. So, for a "land parcel" (ID 7580-80-2532, I can have 50% of farming use (TYPE FAR-23), and 50% of residantial use (RES-112). In the first array, I'll have 2 rows with the same ID (7580-80-2532), but each one will have a different type (FAR-23, RES-112) and a different %. 
In the second layer, the same the municipal zoning (land use) has changed. So the same "land parcel" will now be 40% of residential use (RES-112), 20% of commercial (COM-54) and 40% of a new farming use (FAR-33).
So, I wanna know if there are some differences. Some land parcels will be exactly the same. Some parcels will keep the same land use, but not the same percentage of each. But for some land parcel, there will be more or less land use types with different percentage of each.

I want this script to compare these two layers and send me an email when there are differences between these two layers for the same land parcel ID.

The script is already working, but it takes too much time.

The probleme is, I think, the script go through all array2 for each row in array 1.

What I want is when there are more than 1 rows with the same ID in array1, take only this ID in both arrays.

Maybe if I order them by IDs, I could write a condition. kind of "when you find what you're looking for, stop searching when you'll find a different value?

It's hard to explain it clearly because I've been using VB since last week.. And english isn't my first language! ;)

Comment: Is the data organized (i.e. sorted) in any particular way?

Comment: no, it's not sorted in any way. I didn't write the code. I got this new job and my boss asked me.. get it working faster.. yuk

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a structure to store this data. We'll store all the data in a `LandParcel` class, which will have a `HashSet<ParcelData>`

```
public class ParcelData
{
    public ParcelType Type { get; set; } // This can be an enum, string, etc.
    public int Percent { get; set; }

    // Redefine Equals and GetHashCode conveniently
}

public class LandParcel
{
    public ID Id { get; set; } // Whatever the type of the ID is...
    public HashSet<ParcelData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have to build your data structure, with something like this:

```
Dictionary<ID, LandParcel> data1 = new ....

foreach (var item in array1)
{
    LandParcel p;

    if (!data1.TryGetValue(item.id, out p)
        data1[item.id] = p = new LandParcel(id);

    // Can this data be repeated?
    p.Data.Add(new ParcelData(item.type, item.percent)); 
}
```

You do the same with a `data2` dictionary for the second array. Now you iterate for all items in `data1` and compare them with the item with the same id for `data2`.

```
foreach (var parcel2 in data2.Values)
{
     var parcel1 = data1[parcel2.ID]; // Beware with exceptions here !!!

     if (!parcel1.Data.SetEquals(parcel2.Data))
         // You have different parcels
}
```

(Now that I look at it, we are practically doing a small database query here, kind of smelly code ...)

Sorry for the C# code since I don't really feel so comfortable with VB, but it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I'm not sure I can compare position in both arrays, because there can be 3 rows with ID 3 in array1, and 5 rows with ID 3 in array2. They aren't equal sequences.. :(

Comment: Then I didn't understand the problem at all :(, sorry for that. I thought the point was to identify if both sets were unequal. Now, reading your edit, I think you have to store the data in a better structure than an array. I will edit my answer.

Comment: As I see now, this is very much like the previous answer from @Meta-Knight. Hope it clarifies something.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find out if there are any differences between the first and second array, you could do:

```
Dim diff = New HashSet(of Polygon)(array1)
diff.SymmetricExceptWith(array2)
```

diff will contain any Polygon which is unique to array1 or array2. If you want to do other types of comparisons, maybe you should explain what you're trying to do exactly.

**UPDATE:**

You could use grouping and lookups like this:

```
'Create lookup with first array, for fast access by ID
Dim lookupByID = array1.ToLookup(Function(p) p.id)

'Loop through each group of items with same ID in array2
For Each secondArrayValues in array2.GroupBy(Function(p) p.id)

    Dim currentID As Integer = secondArrayValues.Key 'Current ID is the grouping key

    'Retrieve values with same ID in array1
    'Use a hashset to easily compare for equality
    Dim firstArrayValues As New HashSet(of Polygon)(lookupByID(currentID))

    'Check for differences between the two sets of data, for this ID
    If Not firstArrayValues.SetEquals(secondArrayValues) Then

        'Data has changed, do something
        Console.WriteLine("Differences for ID " & currentID)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm gonna test it and give some news if it works or not! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question based on the first part that you wrote (that is without the EDIT section).  The correct answer should explain a good algorithm but I am suggesting you to use DB capabilities because they have optimized many queries for these purpose.

Put all the records in DB   two tables - O(n) time  ... If the records are static you dont need to perform this step every time.
Table 1 
id type percent

Table 2
id type percent

Then use the DB query, some thing like this 
select count(*) from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.id!=t2.id and t1.type!=t2.type
(you can use some better queries, what I am trying to say is give the control to DB to perform this operation)
retrieve the result in your code and perform the necessary operation.

**EDIT**
1) You can sort them in O(n logn) time  based on ID + type + Percent and then perform binary search.
2) Store the first record in hash map with appropriate key - could be ID only or ID+type
this will take O(n) time and searching ,if key is correct, will take  constant time.